# How do I perform certain actions in InstallShield in all situations other than a repair?

Tags: iis, windows-installer, installation, installshield, custom-action

I've configured an InstallShield setup to delete certain VDs from IIS right before the InstallFiles action. The code is being called within the "OnInstallFilesActionBefore" event. This works fine, except that I don't want the VDs to be removed if the setup is repairing.

I've found [this page](http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/devstudio9helplangref/LangrefEventHandlers.htm) which lists the possible events; however, it seems the best option I have is "OnFirstUIBefore", which only happens in the first-time installation. It just doesn't seem right to do it there, though.

Am I better off adding a condition to one of the Sequences, one that would prevent it from executing the code during a repair? Is there another way?

For the record, I'm using DevStudio v9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add a condition, nothing wrong with that. Try `REMOVE~="ALL" OR NOT Installed`.

Comment: edit: I got the condition exactly reverse to what you needed.

Comment: lol - yeah, I noticed that when implementing it. You still had the right solution in mind, and you even commented on your mistake before I got around to it. Thanks for the help!